# HTML form error each time I refresh web page

Tags: html, forms, page-refresh

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOT1x.png)

Hi. My HTML form loads perfectly. But when I "refresh" the web page, the form automatically moves to the left (see attached image). Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance! -lion

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the form appears to quickly jump to the left side of the screen, and back to the right when I open OR refresh the screen on both Android and iOS mobile devices.

Comment: Hi there. Please share some code or a link to the site.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding. The web address is --> wallofcomps.com

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue -->

I had to make the "width" of both **containers** = to the "max-width" of the **form**. I'm pretty new at programming, so this is a huge boost for my morale - makes me want to keep learning.

```
.container2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -35px auto;
}
.container3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -35px auto;
}
```

Thank you all for the suggestions :) Cheers! -lion

Comment: Just made the mistake of entering the same "max-width" in both containers, and realized that the mobile container needs to be smaller than the container for larger devices / screens. That said, if anyone else has the same issue, make SURE you enter the correct "max-width" of each container. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
form { 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

put this in your css this may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already have that in my CSS - see attached code

Comment: I created 2 different sized "form-rappers" in order to make the page responsive. Perhaps I did something wrong there..?

Comment: working fine on my mozilla!

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for letting me know. The issue has been occuring on Safari and Chrome

Comment: if you are using old version of bootstrap. try using latest one

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just found the issue. I will post the the way I fixed in a few minutes :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some of my CSS:

/* NOTIFY ME */

```
.container2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -35px auto;
}
.form-rapper {
    border: 1px solid; 
    color: #1e5a88;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 335px;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 13px;
}
.container3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -35px auto;
}
.form-rapper1 {
    border: 1px solid; 
    color: #1e5a88;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 375px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 13px;
}
```

Comment: it seems alright to me. try removing cache of your browser

Comment: Thanks :) Tried that also. I'm not sure what the issue is...

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this not too long ago and this is what worked for me:

```
form {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. Tried the code, but it didn't correct the issue. Cheers!